# Configuring Applications that use the same domain to use different ports

Tags: windows, iis, iis-7

I have an IIS7 server hosting 2 applications behind the same URL.

```
https://example.com/application1  
https://example.com/application2
```

I would like to use one port for application 1, and a different one for application 2 such as

```
https://example.com:1234/application1  
https://example.com:4321/application2
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm.. Just realized this is pretty basic and easy. Simply add another site to IIS and configure the binding with a different port.

Answer (score 0):

In response to your own answer, yes that is how you create sites on different ports.  However there's no need to split your app between different ports just to host mulitple websites on the same server.  By standard, Web Traffic should always use port 80.  There's a better way than using different ports to host multiple apps on the same web server....

For a locally hosted solution on your dev machine, edit the host file

The host file is located at C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc

add the following lines:

```
app1.mysite.local     127.0.0.1

app2.mysite.local     127.0.0.1
```

This means any DNS Requests to app1/2.mysite.local will resolve to your local machine - the request will never hit the DNS server.

Then, add bindings for both sites pointing to the relevant directories, with the appropriate domain name (app1/2.mysite.local) in the binding.  When IIS receives a request, it inspects the host Header to see what site has been requested, then returns app1 or app2 depending on the address.  Two apps, one IIS Server, one port.

In Production, the way to do it would be to use Application Request Routing:

http://www.iis.net/download/applicationrequestrouting

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/489/using-the-application-request-routing-module/

Which will route different paths to different locally hosted websites.

I'm kind of answering this assuming you don't really want to use different ports, and that you're only doing so because you think you have to, you don't.  There are better ways to host multiple apps on the same webserver.

Comment: I actually do want to use different ports. I have a webservice I want hosted behind one port, and a site that I want behind another. Right now I am trying to do it by having 2 sites in IIS each with it's own binding. Seems rather unelegant tho...

Comment: well in your example I'd have www.mysite.com:80 for your website and api.mysite.com:80 for your WebService.  Web Traffic uses Port 80....  why do they need to be on different ports?